# discord.py - Check if subcommand is not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have a command group, in a cog, called 'todo', and when it's called by itself (ie without a subcommand), it shows a to-do list. If the subcommand doesn't exist, then it shows a message (because otherwise, it just shows the to-do list regardless). The problem is with the latter, I can't get the if-statement to work.

```
@commands.group()
    async def todo(self, ctx):
    # Main todo command with subcommands, shows list

        if self.bot.get_command(f"todo {ctx.invoked_subcommand}") == None:
            # the API has said that it returns None if subcommand is not found
            await ctx.send("Sorry, the `c!todo` command doesn't have that option.")
        elif ctx.invoked_subcommand is None:
            # code that shows list
```

With this code, it sends the message even if I type an existing subcommand or if I don't type a subcommand.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `Context.invoked_subcommand` will either return a `Command` object or None. So you do not need to use get_command here, as it will already be the Command obj you need.

So instead just check if invoked_subcommand is not None

Comment: When I do try that, it also shows the message when I type a subcommand that does exits. It also still shows the list even if I type gibberish for the subcommand. Is there another way to check if the subcommand doesn't exist? maybe something that also uses your suggestion, like in this pseudocode: `if invoked_subcommand is not None AND invoked_subcommand doesn't exist: show message`

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. by checking if ctx.invoked_subcommand is not None it will only pass if the command is a real command. I've tested this and I only get the message if the command isn't real.

Comment: Ah I see, I think I misunderstood the code usage. For my code, when I check if invoked_subcommand is None, it shows the list if I typed `c!todo` by itself (which is how I intend it to be) OR if I type it with a subcommand that doesn't exist, like `c!todo play` (I'm assuming because nonexistent commands return None in the end, right?). So my main question was if there was a way to prevent the todo command from showing the list if the user typed a nonexistent subcommand/gibberish. If it's too complicated, I think I can just add another subcommand to the group in the end, like `c!todo show`.